# Insertion at the end of a linked list is not a special case. So what about the end of an array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, linked-list

So, I was reading my textbook about linked lists. So if it isn't a special case if something is inserted at the end of a linked list, is it a special case, by way of contrast if an element is inserted at the end of an array? What is the reason behind the answer. Why? Why isn't it a special case when inserted at the end of a link list and why is/isn't a special case at the end of an array? What about for ArrayLists?

Comment: What's a special case?

Comment: It isn't possible to insert a value at the end of the array if the index of insertion exceed the defined size.  But a `List` will allow a value to be inserted at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is also not a special case for `Array` (if we are not talking about exceeding bounds of `Array`). But for `ArrayList` it could be a special case, because `ArrayList` has a capacity and if it is exceded `ArrayList` needs to be resized in order to make sure that it has space for inserted element.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays have a fixed size that you give at initialization (This part is important because array elements are stored at consecutive memory addresses). Hence, you cannot append an element to an array without creating a new array.

```
int[] myArray = new int[10];
myArray.append(42); //Where should it be stored? It would not make sense.
```

For lists, it depends on the list implementation. The LinkedList consists of several `Node` connected to each other. Hence, adding an element to the end of the list is equivalent to connecting a new Node to the last Node of the list.